# xstring switch default argument error

Tags: xparse, xstring

I am trying to create a command to display norm:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}

\NewDocumentCommand \norm {d<> g} {
    \left\lVert
    \IfNoValueTF{#2} {
        \cdot
    }{
        #2
    }
    \right\rVert
    \IfValueT{#1} {
        _{
        \IfStrEqCase{#1} {
            {u}{\mathrm u}
        }[#1]
        }
    }
}

% Test code
\begin{document}
\[ \norm{f},\norm<u>{g},\norm<2>{F\cdot}
\]
\end{document}
```

The result should be: `||f||, ||g||_u, ||F.||_2`

The third case, `\norm<2>{...}` invokes the default argument which uses `2` as a subscript, but it gives an error:

`@xs@testcase has an extra }`

Comment: Please, rethink to your choice of the optional argument delimiter and be careful with unprotected end-of-lines in definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

In a `IfStrEqCase` statement:

```
\IfStrEqCase{Val}{{k1}{v1}...{kn}{vn}}[default]
```

There should be no space/newline in between the last value `{vn}` and the enclosing curly bracket `}[default]`